# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

I've seen similar errors on SO, but I don't find a solution for my problem. I have a SQL query like:

```
select a.abc,b.acd
from A,B,C
Cross Apply fnGet(A.id) D
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
AND D.CHILD = C.CHILD
```

When I execute this query, the error result is: The multi-part identifier "A.ID" could not be bound. Is this due to CROSS APPLY i am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ANSI 92 join syntax rather than comma separated joins

```
SELECT a.abc,
       b.acd
FROM   A
       JOIN B
         ON A.ID = B.ID
       CROSS APPLY dbo.fnGet(A.id) D
       JOIN C
         ON D.CHILD = C.CHILD
```

Comment: any issue in above query?

Comment: The order of precedence of the comma operator